# String was not recognized as a valid Boolean when added to visible attribute

Tags: c#, listview, visibility, itemtemplate

I'm trying to add a true or false Visible attribute to my `listview` `itemtemplate` table. What I did is that I have a hiddenfield that is set at page load so that I can make a specific column visible or not. This is my hiddenfield and column:

Hidden Field

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="uoHiddenFieldPriority" runat="server" Value="false" />
```

Td column

```
<td class="leftAligned" visible='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(uoHiddenFieldPriority.Value)) %>' >
some Text
</td>
```

This is my code in the backend:

```
  int visibility = 0;
  if (visibility = 0)//sample condition I am using to test if the value is changing
     {
        SelectTH.Visible = false;// this is working, this is for the column header
        uoHiddenFieldPriority.Value = "False"; //this is not
                }
```

What happens is that the error "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean" is thrown. I am not really that proficient with c# which is why I decided to use this way of getting the visibility of a column.

Comment: Remove the quotation marks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are assigning the String value `"False"` to the `Boolean` property so before assigning it ,you should convert it properly using `Convert.ToBoolean()` method.

OR

You can assign Boolean value `false` directly without having any quotation marks.

Replace This:

```
uoHiddenFieldPriority.Value = "False";
```

With This:

```
uoHiddenFieldPriority.Value = Convert.ToBoolean("False");
```

OR

```
uoHiddenFieldPriority.Value = false;
```

Comment: But I'm passing it inside a hiddenfield, which is a string. can I change my hiddenfield so it could accept boolean values?

Comment: can you show how you are passing it in hidden feild.

Comment: If you're assigning it to a string-typed variable: `string str = "" + false;`