# In C#, how to take null input from keyboard into nullable type boolean variable?

Tags: c#, exception, boolean, nullable, keyboard-input

I want to do something like this -

```
using System;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        bool? input;
        Console.WriteLine ("Are you Major?");
        input = bool.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
        IsMajor (input); 

    }


    public static void IsMajor (bool? Answer)
    {
        if (Answer == true) {
            Console.WriteLine ("You are a major");
        } else if (Answer == false) {
            Console.WriteLine ("You are not a major");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine ("No answer given");
        }
    }

}
```

Here if user gives no answer and simply presses enter, the variable input must store the value `null` and output must be `No answer given`.

In my code, input of `true` and `false` is working fine.

But if no input is given and enter is pressed the compiler throws the exception

```
System.FormatExeption has been thrown
String was not recognized as a valid Boolean
```

So how to get `null` value stored in variable `input` so that output is `No answer given`

Here,

the question [String was not recognized as a valid boolean C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010816/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-boolean-c-sharp)

is obviosly not a duplicate as it does not want to take null input directly from keyboard. And if such input can't be taken, what is the utility of nullable type, as there would be work around as well?

Comment: Read the console input into a string, then use bool.TryParse.

Comment: But that is a way around. Can direct null input be taken as should be in case of nullable data type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String was not recognized as a valid boolean C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010816/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-boolean-c-sharp)

Comment: No, obviously not, otherwise your code would work already. This is exactly why TryParse exists.

Comment: @mjwills no it is not a duplicate, I want direct null input from keyboard

Comment: @mjwills no it is not my answer, it has no mention of nullable data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool? finalResult = null;
bool input = false;

Console.WriteLine("Are you Major?");

if (bool.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
    finalResult = input;
}
```

Using the above technique `finalResult` will be `null` if the input cannot be parsed as either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 4):

```
bool input;
Console.WriteLine("Are you Major?");
if (!bool.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
{
    Console.WriteLine("No answer given");
}
else
{
    //....
}
```

Or using **C# 7**:

```
if (!bool.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out bool input))
{
    Console.WriteLine("No answer given");
}
else
{
    // Use "input" variable
}
// You can use "input" variable here too
```

Comment: Good answer, but I don't want to do it this way. What is the utility of nullable data type then? There will be workaround, when nullable data type is not used, as well.

Comment: @Suraj For instance, in Entity Framework. When `bit` column in database allows `null`s (IsAttached bit null), then you must use `bool?`.

Answer (score -2):

You could surround your parse with a try-catch, and on catch (so if something other than true or false is given by the user) set input to null.

Comment: That is a way around. Can directly null input can be taken as it should be in case of nullable data types?

Comment: No this is not possible. If you don't enter anything, Console.ReadLine() will return the empty string, so you have to do something yourself with it (i.e. using String.IsNullOrEmpty())